# Starting mariaDB container and start-up script with Docker

Tags: java, docker, mariadb, docker-java

I'm creating a mariaDB container via `docker run` with `-v pathToSQL:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql` option via Java. I have no idea how to find out when the container is ready to be connected with my JDBC client. How can I find out when the initial script stopped executing and the DB is ready to work? I'd like to avoid something like `Thread.sleep(20000)`, which is my current solution. I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
Execute command
IF
    return OK then connect do DB
ELSE
    wait 5 second and execute command again.
```

Comment: Can you tell us which image you're using or an output of the Dockerfile, as well as the full docker run command?

Comment: @rahoogan I'm using the latest mariadb image and whole run command looks like this: "docker run mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname -v C:/script.sql:docker-entrypoint-initdv.d/scirpt.sql -p 3310:3306"

Comment: When I run this command on my machine: `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname -p 3310:3306 -v C:/script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql mariadb`, it seems to work for me - the logs get printed to console, and I can see: `2018-07-24 13:23:23 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections`. You can also inspect logs at anytime with `docker logs <container id>`

Comment: But I'm usign https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java , so I don't see logs when I start my container.